# Sharing std::vector of pointers through threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, std

I would like to share a std::vector of pointers through threads. Each thread should have the ability to get or delete a pointer and remove it from the vector. How could I make this thread safe and is there anything from the C++ Standard Library that does this already?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take a look at [Ask]. It would be very helpful to others if you included your attempted code!

Comment: XY problem warning. There's probably a better solution to your problem, not involving sharing a vector of pointers...

Comment: Short answer to how to make _any_ shared data thread safe:  Each thread locks a mutex before it accesses the data, Each thread keeps the mutex locked for as short a time as possible, Each thread ensures that the data are in a consistent state--safe for other threads to see--before it unlocks the mutex.  Note that "Access" includes merely _looking_ at the data. You usually don't want one thread to be looking at data when another thread is only half-way done changing it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply write the class and guard the member functions with synchronization object (a critical section).

Look at [this](https://mfreiholz.de/posts/make-a-class-thread-safe-cpp/) example.